# make distance between all tick marks equal in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have created the following graph:

[image: scatterplot]

However, I do not like the fact that the tick marks with the numbers 4,12 and 24 look scrunched together. Is there a way for me to make the distance between all tick marks equal, regardless of the numbers associated with them?

Here is the data I used to make this graph:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
hour  mean   SE
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  4  1.02 0.00568
  8  0.83 0.00671
 12  0.76 0.00831
 24  0.68 0.0129 
 48  0.6  0.0116 
 72  0.56 0.0247 
 96  0.57 0.0259 
120  0.6  0.0548 
144  0.55 0.0429 
168  0.42 0.0243
```

and here is the code I used to generate the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data3, aes(x = hour, y = mean)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width=.2) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line()+
      ylab("Mean speed (km/h)") +
      scale_x_continuous("Hours between locations", breaks = breaks) +
      theme_classic()
```

Comment: `aes(x = factor(hour) ...`

Comment: If I try this, I get the following error message: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: Why would you do that?  That would distort the spacing and show the change in 4 hours is the same as the change in 24 hours. I would remove the part `breaks = breaks`

Comment: Mainly for aesthetics. The way it is currently, the 4-8-12 section doesn't look very legible. Open to other suggestions besides changing the distance if you have some!

Comment: Is it necessary to label every tick mark? A graph typically is more about showing the overall features of the data, rather than the value of every point.

Comment: In this specific situation, yes.

Comment: Are you seeing this on a screen, or when saved to an image file? The output looks fine on my monitor (which is quite wide). I think if you exported to _e.g._ PNG with appropriate width and height, the spacing would be improved.

Comment: Maybe `trans = "log2"` in `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: Why not just use `aes(x = factor(hour))` together with `scales_x_discrete()`. You change the mapping, you better change the scale with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s generally a bad idea to change a continuous scale to use arbitrary spacing in the way you’re looking to — the resulting viz won’t accurately show the rate of change over time.

Instead, here are some alternatives you can use, alone or in combination, to clean up the breaks while maintaining scale and covering the smaller increments on the left.

Use major and minor gridlines:

```
library(ggplot2)

breaks <- seq(0, 168, by = 24)
minor_breaks <- seq(0, 168, by = 4)

p <- ggplot(data3, aes(x = hour, y = mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width=.2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  ylab("Mean speed (km/h)") 

p +
  scale_x_continuous("Hours between locations", breaks = breaks, minor_breaks = minor_breaks) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or major and minor axis ticks:

```
library(ggh4x)

p +
  scale_x_continuous(
   "Hours between locations", 
   breaks = breaks, 
   minor_breaks = minor_breaks,
   guide = "axis_minor"
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Or label the points directly:

```
p +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = hour), 
    size = 8/.pt,
    nudge_x = 5, 
    nudge_y = 0.025,
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
   "Hours between locations", 
   breaks = breaks
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Or combine all three approaches:

```
p +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = ifelse(hour %% 24 != 0, paste0(hour, "h"), "")), 
    size = 8/.pt,
    nudge_x = 7.5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
   "Hours between locations", 
   breaks = breaks, 
   minor_breaks = minor_breaks,
   guide = "axis_minor"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]